# Is there a way to generate a new HTML file, ideally utilising a gulp plugin?

Tags: gulp

I've stripped down the content to hopefully make my question easier to read

```
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>    
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f2f2f2" align="center">    
  <!--===================
  Content goes in here
  ====================-->    
  </table>
  <script src="./dist/logic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Most of my content is generated using javascript.

So far I have been `console.log()`ing the generated HTML and copying that into a new HTML file. 
I've been learning gulp to compile SCSS and JS and I'm wondering if there is a gulp plugin to output a new HTML file with the rendered HTML markup.

I've tried googling 'output HTML file gulp' and 'generate HTML file using gulp'. I've had no luck, I'm sure my searching skills are bad.

Is there a way to generate a new HTML file, ideally utilising a gulp plugin?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks
Moe

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('build', function () {
  gulp.src(['./index.html'])
    .pipe(htmlbuild({
      // build js with preprocessor
      js: htmlbuild.preprocess.js(function (block) {

        // read paths from the [block] stream and build them
        // ...

        // then write the build result path to it
        block.write('buildresult.js');
        block.end();

      })
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

Comment: try this  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlbuild

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Definitely trying it out.

Comment: Let me know if need more info

Comment: @Kasiriveni I installed gulp-html-build and followed the guide. I get the error in my terminal: `htmlbuild is not defined`. Gulpfile is in the post. Have I done it incorrectly. I can give you any more info you need.

Comment: can you share the gulpfile.js  in https://gist.github.com/

Comment: sure, @Kasiriveni
https://gist.github.com/moehammoud/c945073fd18ac2dbcd0c0d7df91a6cef

Comment: share the package.json also

Comment: I've updated it with the package.json file. thanks, @Kasiriveni